# How to get standard code snippets in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2

In a screencast, I saw the speaker type `nav>ul` and then pressed TAB (I think) which turned the text into:

```
<nav>
  <ul></ul>
</nav>
```

however, when I press tab, I only get:

```
nav><ul></ul>
```

He also expanded this:

```
nav>ul>li*5
```

into a nav element with on ul and five li elements, very useful, I want to do be able to do this, too.

Are these snippets that he has made that I would have to make as well, or are there standard snippets which I can download, or am I just not pressing the right snippet-trigger button (tab) to do these very useful code completions for standard HTML code blocks?

Answer (score 4):

This short notation of a HTML structure is normally archieved by using a tool, which is either integrated into the text editor by default, or it might come as a seperate plugin.

I guess the most popular one is called [Emmet](http://emmet.io/), previously known as 'Zen Coding'.

Emmet is available as plugin for most common text editors and IDEs.

You can visit their site at: http://emmet.io/